# PHP Change parent class at runtime?

Tags: php

I have a parent class that depends on whether child class are instantiated.

```
class GoogleApp {
    protected $auth_token;

    public function __construct($scopes) {
        $this->auth_token = $scopes;
    }
}

class Gmail extends GoogleApp {
    public function __construct() {
        print_r($this->auth_token);
    }
}

$googleApp = new GoogleApp('gmail'); // Change the actual class for all child instances
$gmail = new Gmail();
```

The idea is that all the children use the same auth_token (which is generated on whether the child classes are used - as of now, I'm just manually adding them to whether I included them in my code). Since I have quite a few child classes (like Calendar or Drive), do I have to inject the parent into each child instance or is there an easier way?

Comment: You have to make `$auth_token` property `static` and change its value by static method

Comment: could you provide a code example, I thought you couldn't change static properties.

Comment: Static properties may be changed at any time. Most likely you confuse it with constants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, you're pretty close, you just need to declare your property as static.

```
class FooParent
{

    protected static $scope = null;

    public function __construct($scope)
    {
        self::$scope = $scope;
    }

    public function getScope()
    {
        return self::$scope;
    }

}

class FooChild extends FooParent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (self::$scope === null) {
            throw new Exception('Must set scope first.');
        }
    }
}

$parent = new FooParent('foo');
$child = new FooChild();
echo $child->getScope(), "\n"; // prints "foo"
```

Comment: Thank God I asked, I was almost going to do injections! YIKES

Comment: hey alex, if my other classes depend on the parent class haven't that static property set, is there a way to say it must be set before you instantiate a child class?

Comment: Sure, just check that it's not empty when instantiating a child. See my edit.

Comment: I see, sorry for the very straightforward question :) thanks!